# Why am I seeing "Unexpected token, expected ..." in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

Okay, so I'm just starting to get the hang of React Native when I get this error:

```
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError in /AlbumDetail.js: Unexpected token, expected ... (39:20)
```

I can't for the life of me figure it out, and haven't seen the issue anywhere on Google, etc

In AlbumDetail.js:

```
<CardSection>
  <Button onPress{() => console.log('pressed')} />
</CardSection>
```

In Button.js:

```
const Button = ({ onPress }) => {
    const { buttonStyle, textStyle } = styles;
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle}>
            <Text style={textStyle}>
                Click me!
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};
```

And when I change the line in AlbumDetail.js to just this, it works:

```
<CardSection>
  <Button onPress{} />
</CardSection>
```

Please save me, sweet people of Stack Overflow! I love you in advance :)

Comment: You forgot `=`  sign. `onPress={() => console.log('pressed')}`

Comment: `onPress={  }` <- you're missing an assignment

Comment: Doh! Of course. Thank you @Prakashsharma I love you guys.